# How to get around inability to overload on return type in C++

Tags: c++

I have function which can create a number of different templated types; an simple example of the problem would be:

```
EncodedMsg<?>* encode(const Msg& msg)
{
    if(msg.qty < 100) 
        return new EncodedMsg<short>(...);
    else if(msg.qty < 100000)
        return new EncodedMsg<int>(...);
    else 
        return new EncodedMsg<long>(...);
}
```

The issue I have is that:

1. The decision as to what to template on is decided inside the function
2. I can't overload on return type
3. I don't want to return a base class type of EncodedMsg as I'll then have to decode what type of message it is later on

Can anyone think of a way around this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are attempting to use templates in a dynamic fashion, which isn't possible. The template's type must be known at compile time, so you can't differentiate based on a series of conditionals.

To change type at runtime, you'll need polymorphism from classes and inheritance.

Answer (score 3):

Basically, if the test variable `msg.qty` is not a compile-time constant, this will be impossible. You have to understand that templates can be used to achieve static polymorphism while OOP (inheritance) can be used to achieve dynamic polymorphism. In other words, templates are resolved at compile-time while virtual function calls are resolved at run-time. You can use both at the same time, but you cannot use them for the same purpose (i.e. they are complementary programming paradigms that each has its own application contexts).

If you could, however, get `msg.qty` to be a compile-time constant of the type `Msg` (i.e. `Msg::qty`, as an `enum` or `static const`), then you can use the `boost::enable_if` library. As so:

```
template <class Msg>
typename boost::enable_if<Msg::qty < 100, EncodedMsg<short> >::type*
encode(const Msg& msg) { return new EncodedMsd<short>(...); };

template <class Msg>
typename boost::enable_if<((Msg::qty >= 100) && (Msg::qty < 100000)), EncodedMsg<short> >::type*
encode(const Msg& msg) { return new EncodedMsd<int>(...); };

template <class Msg>
typename boost::enable_if<Msg::qty >= 100000, EncodedMsg<short> >::type*
encode(const Msg& msg) { return new EncodedMsd<long>(...); };
```

But in the case that you can determine, for a certain class Msg, what template instantiation to use for the EncodedMsg, then it is a lot easier to define it as a nested typedef in the class Msg, and define your encode function as follows:

```
template <class Msg>
Msg::encoded_type* encode(const Msg& msg) { return new Msg::encoded_type(...); };
```

You could also use a type trait (like message_trait or something like that) to define the nested typedef, if you have message classes that are not modifiable.

But, if the msg.qty can only be a run-time value, then there is no choice but to use dynamic polymorphism (i.e. return a pointer to a base class or interface). Or, you can also use a `boost::variant`. In this case, you can do this:

```
boost::variant< EncodedMsg<short>,
                EncodedMsg<int>,
                EncodedMsg<long> >* encode(const Msg& msg)
{
  typedef boost::variant< EncodedMsg<short>,
                          EncodedMsg<int>,
                          EncodedMsg<long> > result_type;
  if(msg.qty < 100) 
    return new result_type( EncodedMsg<short>(...) );
  else if(msg.qty < 100000)
    return new result_type( EncodedMsg<int>(...) );
  else 
    return new result_type( EncodedMsg<long>(...) );
};
```

The above has some obvious problems (like the fact that the result type will be as big as the biggest of the template instantiations of EncodedMsg, but you could solve that with an additional level of indirection (storing pointers to EncodedMsg objects)). And it is not as nice and efficient as a polymorphic alternative if you can find one.

Answer (score 1):

1) You can't overload a return type of a function, but you can overload types
passed to the function and pass by pointer. However, i think this is not what you want, see 2)

2) Basically one has to use a different design approach to the problem:
By using a virtual interface in your base class your method returns the right
class, and one only calls the proper virtual function. You just return the base class (EncodedMsgBase) which can be a EncodedMsg_whatever as long as it's derived from EncodedMsgBase. You can create a template from a base class if you want.

In more complicated scenarios this boils down to an 'how do i create a factory in c++' problem. People usually work around this by passing a base class implementing the *'virtual constructor idiom'*.

Check the c++ faq for more info on that:

http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/virtual-functions.html#faq-20.8

Also keep in mind that by using static typing one can avoid a lot of trouble :)

Answer (score 0):

This approach won't allow you to use `EncodedMessage` everywhere where you wish to further *(because I suspect, for example, `EncodedMessage<long>` and `EncodedMessage<short>` should both be passable to some method, which operates on `EncodedMessages`).*

Although what you're asking for can be done with tricks, I would advise you to rethink your architecture.

You may simply stick to `EncodedMessage<long>` and typedef it as `TheOnlyPossibleEncodedMessage` if it can be used for all message quantities.